# Cancel the last async/await Task before starting a new one

Tags: swift, async-await

There is a table with users. Each cell has buttons for getting a user's number. Different cells (users) have different numbers.

When the button is tapped, a request is sent.

The logic is as follows: if the user doesn't wait for the response and taps on a bunch of other cells, then the current new request should block (stop) the previous one.

I moved the Task into a variable and before making a request, I do task?.cancel().

However, this approach does not work.

I created a simulation of the request by calling the sleep(1) method.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("tap button", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    var counter = 0
    var fooClass = FooClass()

    func showAlert(_ title: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.height.equalTo(48)
            $0.width.equalTo(128)
            $0.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    @objc func tapButtonAction() {
        counter += 1
        Task {
            let result = await fooClass.fetch(counter)
            switch result {
            case let .success(number):
                print(number)
                showAlert(number)
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            case .none:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

class FooClass {
    private var task: Task<Result<String, Error>, Never>?

    func fetch(_ counter: Int) async -> Result<String, Error>? {
        task?.cancel()
        task = Task {
            sleep(1)
            return .success("\(counter)")
        }
        return await task?.value
    }
}
```

**In the screenshot, the result of double-clicking the button is displayed. The result should be "2", not "1".**

[image: example]

Comment: @Sweeper In a real project, instead of sleep(1), a network request takes place.

Comment: If you are using a built-in `async` API like those in `URLSession`, then you don't need to do anything special to handle cancellation. They will handle cancellation correctly. What makes you think that the tasks are not cancelled?

Comment: Your current code should work correctly if you just replace `sleep(1)` with e.g. `URLSession.shared.data(for: ...)`.

Comment: @Sweeper If the internet is Edge or 3G, the issue arises because there is a delay.

Comment: What does "there is a delay" mean? A delay between *what*? Please show a [mcve] showing how you are doing the network call, and describe what undesirable things happen, and the steps leading to that.

Comment: Do the same think you did in `fetch` in the `button` and use `try? Task.sleep` instead\

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a task, it needs to be cancelable. And you don’t want to block the thread.

The `URLSession` `async` methods are cancelable and non-blocking. But `sleep` is not cancelable and blocks the thread. But you can use [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)) instead, which is cancelable and non-blocking. E.g.:

```swift
actor Foo {
    private var priorTask: Task<String, Error>?

    func fetch(_ counter: Int) async throws -> String {
        priorTask?.cancel()
        let task = Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)) // simulating a cancelable network request
            return "\(counter)"
        }
        priorTask = task
        return try await task.value
    }
}
```

Note, I retired the `Result` type (as that is a completion-handler mechanism for passing success/failure results, which is no longer needed in Swift concurrency). I just made it an `async` function that `throws`. Then you can do a more natural `do`-`catch`:

```swift
@objc func didTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    counter += 1
    Task {
        do {
            let string = try await foo.fetch(counter)
            showAlert(string)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I also made `Foo` an actor, to make it thread-safe.

---

Here is my [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("tap button", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    var counter = 0
    var foo = Foo()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        setupView()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    @objc func didTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter += 1
        Task {
            do {
                let string = try await foo.fetch(counter)
                showAlert(string)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func showAlert(_ title: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

actor Foo {
    private var priorTask: Task<String, Error>?

    func fetch(_ counter: Int) async throws -> String {
        priorTask?.cancel()
        let task = Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)) // simulating a cancelable network request
            return "\(counter)"
        }
        priorTask = task
        return try await task.value
    }
}
```